# Converting height data from CSV file to IMG

Tags: python, image, numpy, csv, genfromtxt

I have some height data from a microscope. My question is: How can I convert CSV files to an IMG output and scale the color correctly? The data I have are CSV files like:

```
90,40,50,30,20
11, 2, 7,30,20
90,40,50,30,50
16,40,50, 4, 6
90, 4,50,30,20
...
```

Where the columns are the x coordinates, the rows are y coordinates, and the entries are the z coordinates.

Also it should be over a fixed scale. That means that the generated image should not be generated over the highest and lowest value, so that multiple files are comparable.

What I did so far is:

```
IMG = genfromtxt('RohCSV/{}.csv'.format(filename), delimiter=',')
```

That kind of works, but I have the scale problem. The results are not comparable.

I hope it is kind of understandable.

Comment: What's IMG please?

Comment: Huh? If each row contains an X, a Y and a Z value, why are there 5 fields? Oh, no, you say the columns are the x-coordinates and the rows are the y-coordinates but I don't get that - if the first column is x and that's 90 that means x is 90 but the rows are the y-coordinates so 90 is the row and the column. No, that must be wrong too... what does the first row mean in plain English please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's already the tabular (image) data. Otherwise `genfromtxt` shouldn't work that easily as presented in the question. The comment indeed is misleading, but it only tells us the typical NumPy (image) array indexing (rows = y coordinate, columns = x coordinate). I assume, the only (remaining) question is the "scale", i.e. a min/max normalization from my point of view.

Comment: @HansHirse Ok, thank you. I've never heard of it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you compare outputs. When using Matplotlib for example, you should get a min/max normalized output per default. Let's see the following example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 5))

# Original data/image
IMG = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(IMG), plt.colorbar()

# Min/max normalized data/image
IMG = IMG - np.min(IMG)
IMG = IMG / np.max(IMG)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2), plt.imshow(IMG), plt.colorbar()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

As you can see, the default output of Matplotlib (left) as well as the output of the explicitly min/max normalized data/image (right) are equal.

Apart from that, the presented min/max normalization should be, what you're looking for.

Hope that helps!

```
-----------------------
System information
-----------------------
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc1
NumPy:       1.18.1
-----------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** After clarification in the comment, I guess using the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters in Matplotlib's `imshow` might be the simplest way to go:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def plot_scaled(data, min_scale, max_scale):
    plt.imshow(data, vmin=min_scale, vmax=max_scale), plt.colorbar()


# Original data/image
IMG = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')

# Artificial data
IMG_large = IMG + 10
IMG_even_larger = IMG + 100

plt.figure(1, figsize=(15, 4))
for i, img in enumerate([IMG, IMG_large, IMG_even_larger]):
    plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1), plot_scaled(img, 0, 200)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: New output]

Value 100 has the same color in all three plots.

Comment: Hi HansHirse, 

thank you for your answer. Your code works very well! 

The only problem I have left is, that the `np.min(IMG)` and `np.max(IMG)` are different from image to image. 

My goal is, that for example the height 5000000 is displayed always in the same color in all images. 

I think I need a fixed scale from height to color but I don't know how to accomplish that. 

For now my output is:

https://imgur.com/a/foa3JXg

Thanks a lot for your help so far! 

Best regards
Max

Comment: @Max I updated my answer. For visualization purposes with Matplotlib for example, the easiest way to achieve that is to use the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I wanted!